# how to set a string as nested Json key in Python

Tags: python, json, key

I have a string="[A][B][C]", value="foo"

How to set the string as nested Json key?  i.e.

```
body={}

body[string]=value   # of course doesn't work

print body
```

get below:-

```
{ "A":{
        "B":{
            "C":"foo"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no such function (at least outside web frameworks), but you can make your own:

```
def setPath(body, path, value):
    brace = path.find('[')
    if brace == 0:
        brace = path.index(']', 1)
        prop = path[1:brace]
        path = path[brace+1:]
    elif brace > 0:
        prop = path[:brace]
        path = path[brace:]
    else:
        path = prop

    if len(path) > 0:
        if type(body) != dict or prop not in body:
            body[prop] = dict()
        return setPath(body[prop], path, value)

    body[prop] = value

body = dict()
setPath(body, "[A][B][C]", "foo")
print body
```

Output: `{'A': {'B': {'C': 'foo'}}}`

This doesn't handle arrays though.

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I want! I like the return setPath() part.